# Show gridline in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a c# chart control that shows dates along the horizontal (x) axis. I want to show gridlines only on thosex axis points that represent the start of the month. How may I do this.

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. There's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean mscharts so it could be

```
chartArea.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

The ones corresponding to the datapoints is the `MajorGrid` which can also be toggled similarly.

you can also do the same for the Y axis too.